# SQL Multiple SELECT Statements in one Query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have the following table called approver:

| id | subordinate_id | leader_id | main_leader_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 6 | 5 | 4 |

and the table called user:

| id | full_name | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paulo | 2123 |
| 2 | Marcos | 3322 |
| 3 | Leandro | 43565 |
| 4 | Any Moreira | 23454 |
| 5 | Maria S | 43432 |
| 6 | Jose Oliv | 454567 |

I would like to make a query that brings the name of the users instead of the ids of the approver table, something like:

| subordinate | leader | main_leader |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Leandro | Marcos | Paulo |
| Jose Oliv | Maria S | Any Moreira |

I tried with the following query but I only get one name at a time:

```
SELECT 
    U.full_name as subordinate
FROM user AS 
    U
INNER JOIN 
    approver as A 
ON 
    (A.subordinate_id = U.id);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BlDa.png)

how can i retrieve the user names from the approver table in the same way as i demonstrated in the example above?

Comment: MySQL and PostgreSQL are two entirely different RDBMSs, with different syntax and functionality. It's highly unlikely that you're using both of them at the same time. Please [edit] your post and remove the tag that does not actually apply. If you're not sure which RDBMS you're using, stop trying to write SQL until you figure it out.

Comment: I removed the PostgreSQL tag, since I would guess this question is about MySQL. Please fix the tags if this assumtion is incorrect.

Comment: tks @TheImpaler sorry for the wrong tags!

Comment: tks @KenWhite! sorry for the wrong tags!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this works. You're only joining to the user table once so you are only decoding it once.

```
SELECT u1.full_name AS subordinate,
u2.full_name AS leader,
u3.full_name AS main_leader

FROM approver AS a
INNER JOIN user AS u1
ON a.subordinate_id = u1.id

INNER JOIN user AS u2
ON a.leader_id = u2.id

INNER JOIN user AS u3
ON a.main_leader_id = u3.id
```

Comment: Just a note. When the same table is joined multiple times, then it's critical to add a different "alias" each time. In this case the solutions uses `u1`, `u2`, and `u3` for the same table `user`.

Comment: thank you very much it worked! 
and what exactly do you mean by :  When the same table is joined multiple times, then it's critical to add a different "alias" each time? 

Tks!!!!